# SELECT Query Best practice

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I know that SELECT * is considered bad practice since it can return un-needed information.

But what about this:

Say i have a table with 4 columns, columns 1-4

Is there any difference (like fast, performance) between these two queries?

```
SELECT col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 FROM ...
```

And

```
SELECT col_2,col_4,col_1,col_3 FROM ...
```

FYI : 1st query has same order as database columns,but 2nd query did not care about DB table columns order.

Comment: @Raj Is there different(like fast, performance) between these two queries. SELECT col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 AND SELECT col_2,col_4,col_1,col_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a `where` clause, all the three queries are going to perform the same, assuming that you have listed all the columns in your table. If you have a Primary Key, then these queries are going to do a clustered index scan, otherwise a table scan, which are fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: well i just give you one example.Because lot of time we are not retrieving all columns from one table. But i see you'r point. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, no.

Comment: Yes.that what i thought. I don't know why did i had doubts about this.But i have to tell you these.SELECT * query have lot more problems than it returning un-wanted fields. Thank you very much for you'r help

Answer (score 0):

Speed should be the same in both queries.

To ensure this, print a time stamp before and after each query so you can see for yourself.

Best wishes,